# How to install PHP 7.* on Debian 8.7?

Tags: php, debian, php7

I am looking to install at least PHP 7.0 on Debian 8.7 but from searching around I am finding it hard to find a reliable source that shows me how to do it. It seems so difficult, I have come across DotDeb but I read bad things about using it and I am not sure what the best way to install PHP 7.0 on Debian is?

Comment: What bad things did you read? And why does that scare you off DotDeb but not off Debian itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install it by adding the repository and using the normal apt package management functions.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates -y

sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg \
https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg

echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" |
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list

sudo apt update
# 7.1 is out so select your number accordingly
sudo apt install php7.X -y
```

[Source](http://blog.programster.org/debian-8-install-php-7-1/)

Comment: You also need to state where these packages come from and why you are recommending them.

Comment: The repository is maintained by the the maintainer of PHP in Debian proper: https://qa.debian.org/developer.php?login=ondrej%40debian.org

Comment: In my case `$(lsb_release -sc)` causes problems. Had to replace with explicit version name i.e. `deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ jessie main`